# Using INDIRECT() for chart series formula

Tags: excel, charts, named-ranges

I was looking for some help on a dynamic graph I am trying to create.

To begin with, I have created a named range called PerX with the following formula.

```
='MySheetName!$B$2:$AZ$2
```

When I assign the chart series value to this formula, the chart works fine. Yay!

However, when I try to indirectly reference a different sheet name using the following formula, nothing is displayed. (The value in the cell A1 on sheet name 'Chart' being the name of the other sheet I am trying to pull data from)

```
=INDIRECT("'"&Chart!$A$1&"'!$B$2:$AZ$2")
```

Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong or whether what I am trying to do is possible?

Thanks a bunch

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Just worked it out :)

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&Chart!$A$1&"'!A1"),1,1,1,COUNTA(TA_Skills))
```

Where TA_Skills is the length of the range I need.